# Why does my reverse function not work in C?

Tags: c, string, loops, while-loop, reverse

```
void str_reverse(char *l, char *r){
    char *start = l; //gives while loop place to stop, the start of the string
    while (*l != '\0'){
        *l++;
    } //loops the to the end terminator

    *l--; //last character

    while (*l != *start){
        *r = *l;
        *l--;
        *r++;
    } // adds the string from back to front to new string

    *r = '\0'; 
}
```

Can someone tell me when i print out *r, why im missing the first character? eg, hello reversed is olle? thanks

Comment: Where the first character should be copied? Please point at the line that is supposed to do that.

Comment: *l++ is different than l++

Comment: How are the input arguments `l` and `r` related? Do they point to same location in memory to start with? Is one an input wile the other is the output?

Comment: This changes nothing and doesnt sort the problem @buepixy

Comment: @rsahu they dont, r is an empty string and l is the string to be reversed

Comment: Is `l` to be reversed in place? What's the purpose of `r`?

Comment: I put the reverse of l into r

Comment: Everyone to answering this, thank you very much, there has been many good solutions and you've all gave me very good insight into C programming, thank you!

Comment: @Callum Sangray Do not be hurry. See my answer.:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake is incrementing pointer with defreferencing, like *l++, and comparing the pointers by the value they point at. The fixed code would look like:

```
void str_reverse(char *l, char *r){

char *start = l; //gives while loop place to stop, the start of the string
while (*l != '\0'){
    l++;
    } //loops the to the end terminator

l--; //last character

while (l >= start){
    *r = *l;
    l--;
    r++;
} // adds the string from back to front to new string

*r = '\0'; 

}
```

Comment: This works, there are many solutions to this problem a few people have come up with good answers, thank you!

Comment: @CallumSangray I didn't try to make a one-line neat answer. Your question was "why does my reverse function not work", and I answered exactly that. Hope it helped.

Comment: Alas, this is undefined behaviour. You cannot decrement the pointer past the beginning of the array and then use it for anything (including comparison).

Answer (score 0):

Change to do-while:

```
do {
   *r = *l;
   l--;
   r++;
   // adds the string from back to front to new string
} while (l != start);

*r = '\0';
```

Answer (score 0):

Few of the checks are wrong. 
First 
       `while(*l != *start)` 
The loop will exit without copying the last character.

So the check should be based on address.

```
while(l >= start)
```

Just you need to increment and decrement the pointers  `*l--` and `*r++` is not you intend to do.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void str_reverse(char *l, char *r){

char *start = l; //gives while loop place to stop, the start of the string
while (*l != '\0'){
    *l++;
    } //loops the to the end terminator

*l--; //last character

while (l >= start){
    *r = *l;
    l--;
    r++;
} // adds the string from back to front to new string

*r = '\0'; 


}
int main()
{
   char a[20] = "somestring";
   char b[20];
   str_reverse(a,b);
   printf("%s",b);
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
void str_reverse(char *l, char *r) {

    char *start = l; //gives while loop place to stop, the start of the string

    while (*l != '\0'){
        l++;
    } //loops the to the end terminator

    l--; //skips \0

    while (l >= start){
        *r = *l;
        l--;
        r++;
    } // adds the string from back to front to new string

    *r = '\0'; 
}
```

Note the while condition has changed and also the pointer arithmetic is right.

Comment: Nothing is printed when I do this

Comment: actually, looking at your code you are derrefencing when you shouldnt